# autocmd source vimrc automaticly failed ,said can't open file

Tags: vim

```
autocmd BufWritePost vimrc :source %<CR>
```

this is my config
i want auto source my vimrc after vimrc has written

but some error came out

```
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "vimrc":
E484: Can't open file /Users/xxx/.vim/vimrc<CR>
E484: Can't open file /Users/xxx/.vim/vimrc<CR>
```

I tried many methods but all failed ,please help me

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `<CR>` at the end.

You use it with key mappings, to simulate <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Autocommands use commands normally, you don't need to "press enter" in your config file.

Comment: thanks ! i remove the carriage return then it works!